# What is $Ext^1(X, Z)$ telling us about the middle terms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

Suppose $X, Y, Z$ are modules over some ring $R$ and for which we have the following short exact sequence,

$0\to Z\stackrel{i}{\to} Y\stackrel{p}{\to} X\to 0$.

Then there is a class $c\in Ext^1(X,Z)$ representing this SES. In particular, I know $Ext^1(X,Z)$ is an abelian group under the Baer sum (denoted by $+$ for ease). Moreover, the class $-c$ is represented by the exact sequence,

$0\to Z\stackrel{i}{\to} Y\stackrel{-p}{\to} X\to 0$.

Clearly, then, $Ext^1(X,\,Z)$ is telling us something about the object in the middle $\textit{and}\:$ the maps of the exact sequence. I was wondering if anyone could shed some more light on just what it is telling us.

Further, suppose I know $Ext^1(X,\,Z)\cong\mathbb{Z}/2$, then if $Y_1, Y_2\not\cong X\oplus Z$, then I know $Y_1\cong Y_2$ (by the Five Lemma). However, surely I also know that if $Ext^1(X,\,Z)\cong\mathbb{Z}/3$, and $Y_1,\,Y_2$ are as above then this also implies $Y_1\cong Y_2$. For suppose $Y_1$ (say) exists in the SES,

$0\to Z\stackrel{i}{\to} Y_1\stackrel{p}{\to} X\to 0$

represented by the class $c\in Ext^1(X,\,Z)$. Then the inverse class $-c$ represents the SES

$0\to Z\stackrel{i}{\to} Y_1\stackrel{-p}{\to} X\to 0$.

Now, if $Y_1,\,Y_2$ belong in the same class, then they are isomorphic (again by the Five Lemma). If they are not, then $Y_2$ is represented by the class $-c$ and is therefore also isomorphic to $Y_1$. Is this correct?

If this is true, then can we not say something about how many modules can exist (up to isomorphism) in the middle? So if $Ext^1(X,\,Z)\cong\mathbb{Z}/2$ or $\mathbb{Z}/3$ then we have (up to isomprhism) two modules - the split module and the non-split module. If $Ext^1(X,\,Z)\cong\mathbb{Z}/5$ then we have (up to isomorphism) three modules etc.

Comment: I don't think that the Ext tells you anything about the middle term.

Comment: The automorphism groups of $M$ and of $N$ act on $Ext(M,N)$, and the orbits for that action do give you information about how many isomorphism classes there are of middle terms. But with the group Ext(M,N) without extra information, I doubt you can say anything.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Well, the definition I have seen describes two exact sequences as being congruent when there exists a morphism between the middle terms that induces the identity on both ends (i.e. the $X,\,Z$). If there does exist a congruence, then the morphism is an isomorphism by the Five Lemma. This describes an equivalence relation. We then define $Ext^1(X,\,Z)$ to be the collection of these equivalence class, and it has a group structure induced from the Baer sum. So surely, this is telling us something about the middle terms

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Because if they are in the same class then they are congruent and hence isomorphic

Comment: Not really. If two extensions are equivalent, then they have isomorphic middle terms, but there are many non.equivalent extensions which have isomorphic middle terms. For example, whenever Ext of abelian groups is $\mathbb Z/p$ with $p$ a prime, there are two possible middle terms: the split one and another one, as the extensions corresponding to nonzero elements of that Ext are all in the same orbit under the action of automorphisms of $M$ and $N$.

Comment: It is not even true that the only class in Ext whose middle term is isomorphic to $M\oplus N$ is the zero class.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Well isn't that what I said. That if they are in the same class then they have isomorphic middle terms. Indeed, above I discussed the situation where two different classes can have an isomorphic middle term. Isn't that the case I was talking about with $\mathbb{Z}/2$ and $\mathbb{Z}/3$

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez So, for example, isn't it the case that the middle term in the class $c$ is isomorphic to the middle term in the class $-c$, since $c$ is the class of some extension $0\to Z\stackrel{i}{\to}Y\stackrel{p}{\to}X\to 0$ and $-c$ is the class of the extension $0\to Z\stackrel{i}{\to}Y\stackrel{-p}{\to}X\to 0$. So if $Y_1,\,Y_2$ are middle terms of $c$, then they are isomorphic by the Five Lemma, and if $Y_2$ belongs to $-c$, then it exists in an extension congruent to the one above (with map $-p$) and hence once more isomorphic by the Five Lemma.

Comment: I wrote my comment above while you were writing yours… In any case: the fact that $c$ and $-c$ have isomorphic middle terms is just a very special case of what I said in my second comment above: $c$ and $-c$ are in the same orbit under the action on $Ext$ of the automorphisms of $M$, since multiplying by $-1$ on $M$ is an automorphism. As I said, that is as much as you are going to be able to say. You are free to disagree, of course.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67266/discussion-between-billscroggs-and-mariano-suarez-alvarez).

Comment: Also, and I apologise for bombarding you with these questions. But suppose (as in my question) that $Ext^1(X,Z)\cong\mathbb{Z}/5$. Could you not actually argue about how many isomorphism classes of modules there are. So suppose the non-trivial classes are $c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4$. If $A$ is the middle term of $c_1$, then it is clearly the middle term of $-c_1=c_4$ (say). So, up to isomorphism, we only get one module in these two classes.

Comment: Likewise, if $B$ is the middle term in the class $c_2$, then it is the middle term in the class $-c_2=c_3$. So, up to isomorphism, the only modules we get in these two classes are, up to isomorphism, $B$. As these are the only classes we have, then the only modules we can have, then, are $A, B$ or $X\oplus Z$.

Comment: As I wrote twice, that observation is a special case ofg what I wrote. The automorphism $x\mapsto -x$ of $M$ acts on $Ext^1(M,N)$ as multiplication by $-1$. If the latter abelian group is cyclic of order $5$, then the orbits of this multiplication by $-1$ are three, and that means that there are at most three possible middle terms. There may be less that $3$: for example, if $M$ and $N$ are both $\mathbb Z/5$ then $Ext(M,N)$ has 5 elements but only two possible middle terms. Why? Because in this case there are more automorphisms.